# Time expression

Tags: grammaticality, time

Is it right to write:

1. At quarter (to) seven I have breakfast with my Xyz**.**

My understanding is that it must be:

2. I have breakfast with my Xyz in the kitchen at quarter seven**.**

because I was taught that the time expression must always be the very last part of the sentence.

Comment: Where did you see that "rule"?

Comment: Also "quarter seven" isn't valid English. You can write "quarter *to* seven" and "quarter *past* seven" but not just "quarter seven".

Comment: You can say "half seven" (7:30) (especially if you are a Brit), but not "quarter seven".

Comment: Added fix. The focus is more on the structure (order) of the sentence. Not a big fan of the word "quarter" - prefer to use 15 to 7 (likely this is also broken-English).

Comment: There is no such rule.  Put it wherever you like based on the emphasis you wish to give relative to the emphasis of the other parts.  At a quarter to seven I have breakfast with my wife.  I have breakfast with my wife at a quarter to seven.  I have breakfast at a quarter to seven every day with my wife.  With my wife,  I have breakfast at a quarter to seven.  ...

Comment: +30 years I was a slave of a bad rule. The chains are finally broken. Unfortunately, can't mark your post here as the correct answer. Learned a lot from your answer. Thank you, Jim.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! This is almost correct. However, the correct expression would be either "quarter **to** seven", or "quarter **past** seven".

There is evidence of this in this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quarter%20past%2Cquarter%20to%2Cquarter%20after&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cquarter%20past%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquarter%20past%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuarter%20past%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cquarter%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquarter%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuarter%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cquarter%20after%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquarter%20after%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuarter%20after%3B%2Cc0) search. As you can see, there is much usage of the term quarter **to/past**.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Thanks. Will remember to use `to` the next time :)

Comment: You did nothing to defend or disprove the OP's rule *time expression is always the last part of the sentence*.

Comment: @niamulbengali it will be hard for me to fight for it? As far as I remember from school whenever in a sentence there are an object, place, time => the last part of the sentence should be time expression - helping my kind to finish her homework. Honestly, still didn't get whether we can use both form I've mentioned in the question.